# Mouse not working in xubuntu

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, mouse, live-cd

Hi i am new to the linux world and i decided to install xubuntu 14.04. To test xubuntu 14.04, I booted with the xubuntu live CD into my desktop.

I was pleasantly surprised to find it worked nicely, including the usb Wireless adapter but after installed the mouse was not working and neither the wireless adapter.

I have already reinstalled xubuntu and the problem still continue.

Comment: What is it a pc or a laptop? USB Mouse? UEFI mode? How old is the pc/laptop. Did you use a DVD for installing the system or a USB drive?

Comment: hi is a pc intel core 2 duo, 4 GB of ram, nvidia 7300 and the motherboard is an old biostar G31-M7 TE. I use a usb drive to install the system and yes the mouse is USB.  i think is a usb port related problem because only the mouse and the usb wireless adapter stop working when i turn on the pc. i still use a PS/2 keyboard and all my usb ports are 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you use a USB drive for the installation, than look at this:

http://blog.husainad.com/installing-ubuntu-13-04-mouse-touchpad-not-working/

(From "Installing Ubuntu 13.04" till the end)

UNetbootin could be the reason.

I don't think that it is a USB port problem because it works in the live mode. It must be an install problem.